# Elasticsearch Aggregation using Nested returns empty buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch: v7.2 
Application: Laravel v.5.7

Hello and good day! I'm using Elasticsearch to make a report of my documents, I stumbled upon the need of presenting data fields that are `nested` in nature.

I have the following mappings, I have my index `web` with a field called `ent`:

[image: ENTITIES]

Now I have the following query, using the `aggs`, my goal is to present the entities that have the **MOST** counts that can be found in my documents:

```
'aggs' => [
    'ENT' => [
        'nested' => [
            'path' => 'ent'
        ],
        'aggs' => [
            'TOP_ENTITIES' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field' => 'ent.ent_count'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

What I'm finding weird about this, is that when I'm targeting the `ent.ent_count` field, the buckets works perfectly fine, finding the distinct `ent_count` together with its respective `doc_counts` which portrays the total number of occurence of that `ent_count`:

[image: ENT_COUNT]

**BUT** when I'm targeting the `ent.ent_name` field, it returns empty:

```
'aggs' => [
    'ENT' => [
        'nested' => [
            'path' => 'ent'
        ],
        'aggs' => [
            'TOP_ENTITIES' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field' => 'ent.ent_name.keyword'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

**RESULTS TO**

[image: ENT_NAME]

With `non-nested` fields, this works perfectly fine, am I doing something wrong with my query? because even the examples from the documentation shows the same scripts

Comment: My kind sirs/madams, please notice that I used the `.keyword` string concatenated to `ent.ent_name`, resulting to `ent.ent_name.keyword`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no other way to solve this problem unless you change the `mappings`

So instead of letting the `ent.ent_name` nested field to be of `text` field, we have found out that short words in `nested` fields should be of **KEYWORD** type:

[image: ENT]

After changing the `_mappings` to `keyword`, everything worked perfectly fine